# Getting IDS between two dates; Redesign Table, or Fix SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am not heavy in databases and needed some input. I have a Dates table that is cross joined with a few other tables. I have reports that can be inputted and can be wither a weekly financial report, monthly or daily. I want to get all the ID's between two dates weather it be monthly, weekly or daily. I am thinking that the design of this table is a big problem, would it be better if I compiled a column that was used to hold a time stamp? Or can this design work? The SQL portion doesn't work because of the nested AND and I cant seem to get around this.

By the way, the use case is not for a business more so a personal project.

### SQL

```
  SELECT * FROM Dates
  WHERE ([Day] IS NULL AND [Week] IS NULL)

  SELECT * FROM Dates
  WHERE ([Day] IS NULL AND [Week] IS NULL) 
    AND (
        ([Month] >= '11' AND [Year] = '2013')
        AND 
        ([Month] < '2' AND [Year] = '2014')
        )
```

### Result

[image: SQL Result]

Comment: Are there date columns on the tables with reports themselves? It does sound to me as though the design of the table might be problematic. Would it be possible to keep the date information on the reports (and other data) tables and join them directly as needed for other purposes?

Comment: No they are not, I could add an extra column to the report data but I decided to go this route instead because the report table is about 50 columns in itself and I wasnt sure how to determine if a report was a monthly, weekly or daily.

Comment: There is 3 Total Tables (Dates, Employees, ReportData). ReportData has an ID for (Dates and Employees to join them together). Hopefully that helps.

Comment: One possible design requiring four additional columns would be to add year, month, week, and day (as integers), and to allow null values (or zero possibly for performance) to indicate that the report does not have that level of granularity. Another requiring two columns is to have an enum indicating granularity (monthly, weekly, daily, etc.) and store the start of that period in a second column.

Comment: My hunch here is that the extra DateID as an abstraction for dates is an extra layer of complexity that might best be refactored out.

Comment: The first option would be as I have above right? 
The second option would be a column type of date and another of the report type (if reportType == "Month") { DATEPART(yyyymm, dateField) }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47538/discussion-between-ruquay-and-jon-h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like we figured in the chat, the answer here is that the nested AND ought to be an OR :-)

Comment: SELECT * FROM Dates 
WHERE ([Day] IS NULL AND [Week] IS NULL) 
AND ( 
([Month] >= '11' AND [Year] = '2013') 
OR 
([Month] < '2' AND [Year] = '2014') 
)

Thanks Again!